# Turning result into variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hex, rgb

So I have a snippet takes HEX and turns it into RGB

```
 function hex2rgb(hex) {
            var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
            return result ? {
                r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
                g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
                b: parseInt(result[3], 16)

                }: null;
        }
```

The problem I'm having is that I cannot get the RGB separated. Like `R`, `G`, `B`. They call come out as `RGB`. So my question is how can I only choose what I want to be returned? Say I only want `R` and `G`. Any ideas?

Comment: the return type is an object, so you are free to use the object's attributes..

`var white = hex2rgb('ffffff'); console.log("red value:" + white.r);`

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? What are you using with `hex2rgb()` that's providing the `RGB` output?

Comment: The color is dynamic. So how would I go about on that, instead of using `var white = hex2rgb('ffffff');`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access R, B, G without loading it to a variable by

```
hex2rgb("#00bbff").r
hex2rgb("#00bbff").g
hex2rgb("#00bbff").b
```

Comment: @user302975 Define "*not working*." How are you using `hex2rgb()`? What happens? What did you expect to happen? Are you receiving errors? Which errors?